# How to let Hadoop deploy jars to the cluster?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop

I have read [Using the libjars option with Hadoop](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/) and [Hadoop: Implementing the Tool interface for MapReduce driver](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/hadoop-implementing-the-tool-interface-for-mapreduce-driver/), and I have followed the blog to implement my job runner.

My map reduce functions are implemented in Scala, and the works well if I pack *scala-library* into my jar using **Proguard**. Now I want to separate the *scala-library* so to further reduce my jar size.

After I separated *scala-library*, I ran this command:

```
HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=ALL,console hadoop jar /path/to/my.jar com.scala.mapreduce.Main -files /hdfs/path/to/scala-library.jar -libjars /hdfs/path/to/scala-library.jar /path/to/input /path/to/output
```

- I am **not** sure if I need *-files* option
- I have tried varies path format, including `file:///...`, OS specific format, HDFS format

The error I got indicate hadoop cannot find *scala-library*:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
>   ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you don't need the -files option
2. In addition to adding to the libjars, you also need to add the scala libs to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Here's what we do to add additional jars needed by a MapReduce job.

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:mylib.jar
LIB_JARS=$(echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH | sed -e "s/:/,/g")
hadoop jar ... -libjars $LIB_JARS ...
```

This works pretty well for us. However, we have a policy of only doing this for environment jars (e.g. HCatalog, HBase, etc). Any other jars are packaged into our fat jar. Since all this is behind our firewalls, bandwidth has never been an issue, so we don't worry about size of our jars.

Comment: The 2nd line means I should include all necessary class paths, not just my own jars' class path, is it?...why the doc doesn't say

Comment: You probably don't need to include all the environment jars in libjars... but it was just simpler to write the script this way and does no harm. If it's simpler, you can just include your jar on libjars and append it to HADOOP_CLASSPATH. I'll probably optimize it at some later point.